# How to fix 'Key Error: "['x'] not found in axis" when dropping a line in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a project in which I need to be able to drop a line in a dataframe. However, whenever I try, I get an error no matter what I try

I've tried changing the order of the things in df.drop. I've also tried changing the type of the file to csv without success. And now I can't change it anymore.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Partitions.csv', index_col = 0)
choice = int(input("Which do you want to delete?")
df.drop([choice], inplace = True)
df.to_csv('Partitions.csv')
```

Partitions.csv:

,Composer,Title,

0,Beethoven, Fur Elise

1,Mozart,Symphony 2

I would like to be able to delete any line from the csv file but I always seem to get "Key Error: "['choice'] not found in axis"

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to drop row by iloc, i.e. the serial number of the row. It can be achieved in a roundabout way.

```
df.drop(df.index[i], inplace=True)
```

### Edit - Reason behind

`pandas.DataFrame.drop` by default work on labels, i.e. either index or column. There is no direct way to use the method. So we need to mention the index value of the row that we want to drop, which can be obtained with `df.index[i]`, assuming we want to drop `i`th row from the top

Comment: I tried it with 


    df.drop(df.index[choice], inplace = true)


and I get the following error message
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: What was ur value of `choice`?

Comment: My value for choice was 3